# parallelizing combinations python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

How to parallelize the below code, number of elements in the attributes column is nearly 15 and so combination is taking more time.

```
combs = set()
for L in range(0,len(attributes)+1):
    combs.add(itertools.combinations(attributes,L))
```

Any way to parallelize it using multiprocessing?

I tried this, but i am getting this error. -     if chunksize <= 0:

### TypeError: unorderable types: range() <= int()

```
import itertools     
from multiprocessing import Pool
def comb(attributes):
    res = itertools.combinations(attributes)
    return res

def main():
    p = Pool(4)
    times = range(0,len(attributes)+1)                                                
    values = p.map(comb,attributes,times)
    p.close()
    p.join()
    print(values)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    attributes =('Age', 'Workclass', 'Fnlwgt', 'Education', 'Education-num', 'marital-status', 'Occupation', 'Relationship', 'Race', 'Sex', 'Capital-gain', 'Capital-loss', 'Hours-per-week', 'Native country', 'Probability', 'Id')
    main()
```

Since it was asked to explain the question, here you go... I am trying to get the combination without replacement. Basically n!. For example, if i have A,B,C in my attributes variable, i am trying to get (A),(B),(C),(A,B),(A,C),(A,B,C). Since the number of elements in attributes is not static and it changes based on input dataset, i cant hard code it. So, i am using len(attributes) here, where attributes will store the attributes from the dataset. Then to create combination, itertools.combinations(attributes,L) will generally create all combinations of length L. In my example, if i give length(attributes), then i will get only ABC, not other combinations. So i created a range for length and adding one with it to tackle the zeroth element.

Now coming back to the problem, i may get 15 elements in my dataset and so length(attributes) will be 15 which is 15!. This combination generation takes lot of time as it has to do this factorial. So i am thinking to parallelize this in a way that each processor handles one combination set generation at a time, for example one processor will be generating all the combination of length 2 and other of length 3, etc... But in pool map i am not able to properly pass more than one argument. Hope this clears the situation, let me know if further explanation needed.

Comment: looks trivially parallelizable to me. each subtask is independent, you just have to gather the results. so... what have you tried?

Comment: btw, does it currently finish at all? :)

Comment: Nope, It is taking long time. And, i tried this but got an error that position argument is missing. 
import itertools     
p = pool(4)                                                      
attributes =('Emp', 'Dept', 'Mgr', 'Id')
result = p.map(itertools.combinations(attributes),range(0,len(attributes)+1))
p.close()
p.join()
print(result)

Comment: Yes. Obviously 14! takes lot of time, thats why i am trying to parallelize it.

Comment: please post code in the question.

Comment: Updated the code in question

Comment: the code that you've posted should not take any time at all -- `itertools.combinations()` returns an iterator. What do you want to parallize? What is the result?

Comment: Updated the problem situation as requested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several issues with your multiprocessing code that mean it won't work like your single-process version.

To start with, you're not calling `p.map` properly. The `map` method's arguments are the function to call, the argument (a single sequence), and a chunk size, specifying how many values to pass to a worker at a time. You're passing a `range` object as `chunksize`, which is the immediate cause of your error.

If you try to fix that, though, you'll find other issues. For instance, you're passing `attributes` to `map` in such a way that it will pass just a single value on to each worker process, rather than the whole list of attributes. And your `comb` function returns an iterator over the combination values, not the values themselves (so the worker will complete more or less instantly, but return something that can't be usefully printed out).

Here's what I believe to be working code:

```
import itertools     
from multiprocessing import Pool

# attributes is always accessible as a global, so worker processes can directly access it
attributes = ('Age', 'Workclass', 'Fnlwgt', 'Education', 'Education-num',
              'marital-status', 'Occupation', 'Relationship', 'Race', 'Sex',
              'Capital-gain', 'Capital-loss', 'Hours-per-week', 'Native country',
              'Probability', 'Id')

def comb(n): # the argument n is the number of items to select
    res = list(itertools.combinations(attributes, n)) # create a list from the iterator
    return res

def main():
    p = Pool(4)
    times = range(0, len(attributes)+1)                                                
    values = p.map(comb, times) # pass the range as the sequence of arguments!
    p.close()
    p.join()
    print(values)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This code still takes a while to complete if the list of attributes is large, but that's simply because there are an awful lot of values to print out (the powerset of a set with `n` values has `2^n` subsets). My IDE told me that the output was over 88000 lines (it thankfully didn't show them all). It wouldn't be surprised if the multiprocessing part of the problem is less of an issue as the output part!

Comment: Thanks. I didnt know how to pass multiple arguments for map, thats why the confusion. Thanks anyway, but why we are creating list here? res = list(itertools.combinations(attributes, n)) . It takes lot of memory. isnt it?

Comment: And one more thing, in realtime, attributes will not be static and so it cant be global, i will retrieve the attributes from dataset in the if __name__ == '__main__': . How can i make use of it then?

Comment: @Jeeva: I create a list in the worker process because that's the only way to actually have the work done there. If you just return an iterator (if that even works, I haven't tested it), you will end up with all the work getting done in the main process when it tries to consume the iterator in some way. About how to pass multiple arguments to the worker, `Pool.map` doesn't offer a good way. You can build a sequence of tuples (with `zip` and maybe `itertools.repeat` if you need many copies of the same item), but you'll need to use `Pool.starmap` to pass them as separate arguments to `comb`.

Comment: @Blckknght I experimented with this code, and it takes significantly longer to run the multiprocess version than to run the the regular itertools.combination call. Any idea why?

Comment: @Blckknght recently ran into this issue and on converting `iterator` to `list` was resulting in segfaults.